# How to maintain session and WebDriver initialisation in while running multiple test cases

Tags: selenium, session, webdriver

I have multiple test cases and I have multiple class files one for login, one for user creation and etc. Would it be possible to do like this - I wish to initialise the WebDriver once say in login test case and then wish to execute other test cases by maintaing the session and without re-initialising the WebDriver in further test cases. Is is possible?

Comment: try to write other cases, session continue in your further test cases until an unless you are not closing your browser. Try with next test case and if you found any error than post here.

Comment: Are you using TestNG annotations? on your framework

Comment: this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296953/not-able-to-execute-second-class-from-testng-xml-file/35312613#35312613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not good practice.

Try to avoid this at all cost. Every test should be modular and independent as possible.

Good thing is that You divided them logicaly, but don't go to re-use driver and session, this is just bad practice, and doesn't bring You nothing.

Good Practice:

1. Use **PageObjects** Pattern
2. keep your code robust and portable (Preferred selector order: id > name > css> xpath)
3. Avoid `Thread.sleep` prefer `Wait`
4. keep test as small as possible and Your code modular and re-usable

@murali provided [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296953/not-able-to-execute-second-class-from-testng-xml-file/35312613#35312613) in his link, but as I mentioned this is not good practice.

Hope that this helps,

Comment: Thanks, Kovacic! I am using PageObject pattern. But for me the challenge is to write code for login in each test case which ideally should follow the first one. I'm not sure why it's not a good practice as I'm a begineer to this. And I thank you for providing me the good practices :-) . P.S. if you could explain me WHY its not a good practice to re-use sessions and driver that would be great!

Comment: there are several reasons:
1. how are You certain session will be stable for eg. if session fails at let's say 15/1400 tests, all other tests will fail,
2. Your session initialisation take around seconds/milliseconds, why would You risk to failling all tests because of few milliseconds,
3. hard to debug if something failed in bumnch of tests,
4. maintenance of code to keep session,
5. selenium is not stable with re-using sessions (tried it), depends on different browsers, which don't react same on session re-use
6. drivers often change and session re-use often fails,
....